# Best way to secure an AJAX app+request

Tags: ajax, algorithm, security

I'm trying to impliment Ajax for my app ,

before i go with this , i want to know about few effective ways to protect the ajax requesting frm thefts , which fulfill below conditions ;

say there are 2 files ;which are index.php , ajax.php. Index.php send request to ajax.php file & it's process the request and give the output

> *condition 1: i need to ensure that , the request came only frm index.php*
>
> *condition 2 : say that even though user is a valid user and he/she changes ajax request values , but it(request) won't affect (request won't process) in ajax.php*

to achive these 2 conditions , simply solution is pass a token/code that can't guess !

**so my question is what is the best ways/process/algorithms use for token generation ???**

*info : chk some ideas , but didn't for anything;
not using SSL;
not using session
severer performances are average .

p.s: read this and had alternative solution , but hoping that there better ways than mine ;)

Thanks !

Comment: sorry the previous comment was deleted frm me , my bad !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't really be sure about condition 1 because the HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed.

As far as using a token, it would be fairly trivial to create a token and pair it with a session ID.  The token then gets sent to index.php, and the request to the Ajax web service has to include the token, which is compared to the session ID back on the server.  This is not fully bulletproof, it can be hacked, but it would be fairly safe.

Comment: yeah that's what i used / in my mind

1.get_ip
2.get_rand_no (here as you said for session id )
  eg:md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // csrf protection
3.constant_value =something like secret key

now frm the above it adds "HTTP_REFERER" !!

so what else i can to do this , to expand my security !!

Comment: I don't see how md5 comes into it.  You have to send the token to your index.php, across HTTP.  It's visible.  So all you can do is generate a value (it can be generated any old way), store it in the visitor's session, and send it to index.php.  Then send it back with the Ajax call, and make sure it matches the visitor's session ID.  If you want real security, you need SSL.

Comment: "store it in the visitor's session": vunerable to CSRF , to avoid this i used rand_no=md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); , combine it with

sample:token=md5(ip+key(constant value)+rand_no)+rand_no;

this way it generate something like "ff729b87837192965558d34156627749+1c85d2f6b24f1c601000e1edf87e68b7"

which then  it wuld be prevent(not 100%)  guessing the algorithm !! (*sorry about the half code 1 )

Comment: This is probably due to a gap in my understanding but I don't see how a value stored in the session is vulnerable to CSRF.  Whatever token you send, it will still be visible in HTTP.  If you use what you show above, you have to somehow keep track of the IP, the constant value and the random number, so that when the token comes back, you can confirm it's the right one.  But again I think I'm not understanding something.

Comment: value stored in the session will be there for sometime(until the user log out),in that time if the session is hijacked by someone it's doomed , but with random no generation , it will prevent for some more extent , bcz random no changes within sec.

Comment: ok FYI : say the token generating algorithm is like "sample_token=md5(ip+key(constant value)+rand_no)+rand_no" as above 

so index.php generate the token ; in ajax.php , we get ip(user),key(constant value),$_REQUEST['rand_no'] frm the sample token and generate  md5(ip+key(constant value) & chk the sample token with this . if true user valid , else invalid .

Comment: another thing : Unfortunately $HTTP_REFERER is not foolproof. Some browsers do not send this information, or can be made to send false information. You should keep this in mind when working with $HTTP_REFERER.

http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/HTTP_REFERER.htm